# White space instead of empty string from SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, encoding

I have this query :

```
$this->dbSQLServer->select("nom, '' AS prenom")
                  ->from("users");

return $this->dbSQLServer->get()->result_array();
```

But instead of returning me `''` for the `prenom`, I end up with `' '`.

Any ideas where the problem might come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Following instead:

```
$this->dbSQLServer->select("nom, Null AS prenom")
                  ->from("users");
```

Instead of empty string use `Null`